# How can I use native functions inside Google Spreadsheet AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I simply want to use round(...) method from Spreadsheet inside the Code.gs but the I got the error:

"ReferenceError: round is not defined"

See the attached image (LOC 28).

Note: I added this a few days ago and it was working, but now when I opened it started to complain about that function. Baffled!

[image]

Comment: Math.round() is what you are expecting? Please can a mod delete my answer?It was supposed to be a cooment, but I messed up with my phone 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: @RamónLópezdeAndújar No. I want the round(value, decimals) function you can use inside any Google Spreadsheet. Of course,I can recreate it but why should I reinvent the wheel? I mean what if I want to use other functions already present inside Spreadsheet, do I have to recreate all?

Comment: You can't use the GSheets built-in functions in the script editor directly. Maybe there´s a library, which I haven't heard of, that you could use to call the GSheets functions that I supposse are also written in JS. The round(value,decimals) function could be [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)?

Comment: @RamónLópezdeAndújar That is actually the answer for this problem. Thanks - I write my custom code then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a Community Wiki, since the solution was provided by @Ramón López de Andújar in the comments section.

The error message is related to how the method round is being called is incomplete. To call `round`, you need to use `Math.round()` as mentioned in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp).

I made a simple test for this issue. I added to the cell `A1` the value `1.2`:

[image: A1]

After that, I use the sample code:

```
function roundTest_1() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let range = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  let round_test_1 = round(range);
  Logger.log(round_test_1)
  
}
```

And I got the same error message:

[image: sample]

I also, I test the same method using `Math.round()`, and it works correctly.

```
function roundTest_2() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let range = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue(); //1.2
  let round_test_2 = Math.round(range);
  Logger.log(round_test_2)
}
```

[image: sample 2]

### Update:

As mentioned, in the comments. You cannot use Google Sheet's built-in functions inside an Apps Script. However, you can use other functions, and methods from JavaScript inside Apps Script.

In the comments, the one making reference, to that solved the issue was a function created with `toFixed()`.

Reference information can be found here:

- [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)
- [JavaScript Number toFixed()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)